# get a log file on system performance

Tags: windows, logging, monitoring, performance-testing

I need to monitor my computer's processor usage, RAM usage and disk usage in certain time period and get a log file or some text output with the details of above resource usage. I don't need any complex data but simply usage over time should be enough. I tried few tools including Windows OS's built in Performance Monitor but had no luck. I only need usage over time as a log file or some other simple text manner.

My OS is windows and I don't need to do this in any other OS.

Can anybody help me? Even point me in right direction would be also helpful.

Comment: This question is off topic for SO, is more appropriate for ServerFault, I think, as it doesn't directly involve programming and seems to be asking for a tool or library.  When you post your question, though, you might help yourself by giving more details on why PerfMon didn't work for you or what you're trying to accomplish.  Logging stats over time is pretty much what most systems (Windows and others) have built-in.

Comment: @Paul I need simply only mentioned resource usage over time. perfmon was giving too much details and I cant filter from that load of information. This is about a desktop computer, so I don't think serverfault is a good place for this. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Data Collector Set](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722148(v=ws.11).aspx) which will store the metrics of your choice into .blg file, the file can be opened with Windows Performance Monitor so you will be able to see the counters values in form of zoomable charts.

If you need the data to be in a text format, i.e. in CSV, you can use [Relog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490958.aspx) program to convert it.

---

Alternative option which might be easier is using [Servers Performance Monitoring](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) plugin which is designed for using with [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), this way you will be able to integrate Windows performance counters information with the performance test report. Moreover, it will work on any operating system supported by underlying [SIGAR](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) libraries. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article if interested.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. I'll give it a try.  I just need simple resource usage data against a period of time. to determine how much resources were used in system when I run certain application. to determine how much resources were used at the time that process was running.  I.e: game, virus scan etc..